# argparse: How to call a method instead of a function?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse in my python program and I want to call a **method** when I run my software like this :

```
$ python __init__.py foo
```

It is easy if I want to call a function instead of a method :

```
def foo(args):
    pass

def main():
    foo_parser.set_defaults(func=foo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I replace "func=foo" by "func=MyClass.my_method" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just refer to the method instead of the function. Yup. It's that easy. Instead of

```
 func = foo
```

You do

```
 func = theobject.foo
```

Done!

Comment: Yeah, it's right ! I am sorry because my question was stupid. The problem was not there. I use the @staticmethod instead of declare a instance. Thanks :-)

Comment: What if I need the main parser options to construct `theobject`?

Comment: Get a workaround: args.func.__call__(theobject, args). Is there a better solution?

Comment: @zhigang: Why would you need that? Argparse is for parsing arguments, it shouldn't construct objects.

Comment: It seems I cannot paste my code using comments. I will edit this topic

Comment: @zhigang: No you wont. If you have a new question post a new question. I would have told you before, because you shouldn't ask new questions in comments either, I just don't think your question is a reasonable question.

Comment: @zhigang: I also looked at your proposed edit, I can't see that your code solves any problems or real usecase. It just adds complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You gave the correct answer yourself. Just put:

```
func = Your_Class.your_method
```

instead of:

```
func = foo
```

Comment: Yes, but "your_method" must be a static method (@staticmethod).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
import argparse

class Myclass(object):

    def foo(self):
        print 'foo'

    def bar(self):
        print 'bar'

class Main(Myclass):

    def __init__(self):
        foo_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

        foo_parser.add_argument('method')
        self.args = foo_parser.parse_args()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kws):
        method = self.args.method
        return getattr(self, method)(*args, **kws)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()

    main()
```

example of usage:

```
$ python test.py foo
'foo'
$ python test.py bar
'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "method" you mean "instance method": You can't call an instance method with instance, so you need an instance first. Then, you can just refer to `obj.method` and get a `BoundMethod` which remembers the instance (`obj`) - e.g.:

```
class Cls:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def foo(self, new_x):
        self.x = new_x

obj = Cls(1)
foo = obj.foo
foo(2) # same as obj.foo(), but we don't need to keep obj for this!
print(obj.x) #=>2
```

If it's a static (if so, why? in 99% free functions are simpler to use and work just as well) or class method, just refer to `Cls.method`.